# Why we could not share the denominator for numerators?

Tags: factoring, fractions

For arithmetic question like this

(3*4)/2

2 can divide 3, 3/2 and multiple 4 or

2 can divide 4, 4/2, and multiply by 3

But not

3/2 * 4/2 ,

Could someone explain why this is not possible ? Is there a name why the denominator can not be shared with the numerators?

Comment: For the same reason why $(a+b)-c=(a-c)+b=a+(b-c) \ne (a-c)+(b-c)$. Not all operations are [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) over each other.

Comment: Why should we expect that to be possible? I don't mean this flippantly: in general, every conversion between different expressions should be scrutinized. If you draw some pictures of concrete examples (e.g. think about $1\cdot 1\over 2$ versus ${1\over 2}\cdot {1\over 2}$) I think you'll get a sense for the distinction.

Comment: "2 can divide 3, 2/3..." shouldn't that me $3/2$?

Comment: Division is really multiplication - multiplying by $\frac12$ in this case. $(ab)c=(ac)b=a(bc)\neq (ac)(bc).$ We can rearrange $a,b,c$ by the commutative and associative laws, but we can't add copies of a value.

Comment: Mathematics tells you what things are correct mathematical operations. If mathematics didn't tell you you can do something, you can't do it. We don't need a new name for every thing that mathematics never allowed you to do.

Comment: Like multiplication over addition is distributive , a(b+c)= ab + ac, could we say multiplication over multiplication is not distributive 
1/a (bc)≠(1/a)b *1/a (c)?

Answer (score 1):

In evaluating Algebraic expressions, we must follow rules of Algebra. Those rules come for a reason.

In your question, the two expressions have different 'real life'  meanings. Say you have a big piece of  rectangular cake cut into $3$x$4$ pieces.

If you have $2$ kids, each kid can take $(3*4)/2=6$ pieces.

Now, say you want to give equal number of pieces to $4$ kids, in this case each kid can have $(3*4)/4=(3/2)(4/2)=3$ pieces.

In the first case, each kid's share is $2$ pieces but in case $2$, each kid's share is $3$ pieces only. This is why the two expressions produce different results. Each expression answers a different question.